How can I compress binary or text data in a web browser and then decode it on a server-side in JavaScript?
How can I compress any data in client-side JavaScript before sending it to the server?
E.g.

Text
JSON
Binary data

What kind of compression formats can be used?

Today, web browsers support compression natively in JavaScript.

You can compress any data using common compression methods like Gzip
For images, you can export PNG out of a canvas
Web browsers support Streams API that with CompressionStream
Node.js has zlib built-in that provides some common compression methods (although its interface is very archaic and needs to be tweaked for async).
In web, you might need to base64 encode and decode the compressed payload because embedding it in formats like JSON does not support binary
A good compression format is gzip as it is universally supported

CompressionStream supports only deflate (zip) and Gzip.
An example is how to compress a string (e.g. JSON) on the client-side JavaScript.
Example compress.js:
/**
 * Compress strings and Blobs as gzip.
 * 
 * Based on https://dev.to/ternentdotdev/json-compression-in-the-browser-with-gzip-and-the-compression-streams-api-4135
 * 
 * @param {string | Blob} data Plain-text data as a string or Blob for binary data
 * 
 * @param {boolean} base64 Set true to output base64 encoded (can be embedded in JSON, query parameters, etc.), otherwise return JavaScript blob
 * 
 * @returns {Promise<string | Blob>} Compressed binary or
 */
export async function compressStringGzip(data, base64) {
    
    // Convert incoming string to a stream
    let stream;
    if(typeof data == "string") {
        stream = new Blob([data], {
            type: 'text/plain',
        }).stream();    
    } else {
        // Assume blog
        stream = data.stream();            
    }

    // gzip stream
    const compressedReadableStream = stream.pipeThrough(
        new CompressionStream("gzip")
    );
    
     // create Response
    const compressedResponse = await new Response(compressedReadableStream);

    // Get response Blob
    const blob = await compressedResponse.blob();

    if(base64) {
        // Get the ArrayBuffer
        const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
        
        // convert ArrayBuffer to base64 encoded string
        const compressedBase64 = btoa(
          String.fromCharCode(
            ...new Uint8Array(buffer)
          )
        );        

        return compressedBase64;

    } else {
        return blob;
    }
}

Example decompress.js:
import * as zlib from "zlib";
import * as util from "util";

/**
 * Decompress a string or a Buffer as gzip.
 * 
 * Assume the encoded data compresses as UTF-8 text.
 * 
 * Only for server-side Node.js.
 * 
 * @param {string | Buffer} data Data to decompress, either Buffer or a string
 * 
 * @param {boolean} plainText Set true if the encoded data is utf-8 and you want to decode the string
 * 
 * @returns {Promise<string | Buffer>} Decompressed data as a Buffer object or a string if plainText is set
 */
export async function decompressStringGzip(data, plainText) {

    const gunzip = util.promisify(zlib.gunzip);

    // Assume base64 encoded if we are given data as a string
    if(typeof data == "string") {
        data = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
    }

    const raw = await gunzip(data);

    if(plainText) {
        return raw.toString("utf-8");
    }
    
    return raw;
}

